# Error instanciando clase de servlet

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, web

estoy empezando a aprender a crear proyectos de MVC, pero me está dando el mismo error en todos los proyectos que hago. Llevo poco tiempo programando en Java, no sé muy bien a qué se debe el error.

En lugar de mostrarme la información que estoy solicitando a la BBDD, me muestra lo siguiente:

**"mensaje Error instanciando clase de servlet [webProductos.ControladorProductos]"
"Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento."**

Añado el código del programa que acabo de hacer, es el primero que hago de MVC:

1- Código del Modelo:

```
package webProductos;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.*;


import javax.activation.DataSource;

public class ModeloProductos {

    // AQUI HAREMOS LA CONEXIÓN A LA BBDD
    
    // 1 VARIABLE PARA ALMACENAR EL POOL DE CONEXIONES
    private DataSource origenDatos;
    
    // 2 CONSTRUCTOR PARA RECIBIR POR PARAMETRO EL POOL DE CONEXIONES
    public ModeloProductos(DataSource origenDatos) {
        this.origenDatos=origenDatos;
    }

    // 3 METODO PARA OBTENER EL LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS QUE USARÁ OBJETOS DE TIPO PRODUCTOS Y LO LLAMAMOS GETPRODUCTOS
    public List<Productos> getProductos() throws Exception{
        
        // Creamos la lita para almacenar los productos
        List<Productos> misProductos=new ArrayList<>();
        
        Connection miConexion=null;
        Statement miStatement=null;
        ResultSet miResultset=null;
        
        // 4 ESTABLECEMOS LA CONEXION
        miConexion=((Statement) origenDatos).getConnection();
        
        
        // 5 CREAR SENTENCIA SQL Y STATEMENT
        String instruccionSql="SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS";
        
        miStatement=miConexion.createStatement();
        
        // 6 EJECUTAR SENTENCIA SQL
        miResultset=miStatement.executeQuery(instruccionSql);
        
        // 7 RECORRER EL RESULTSET OBTENIDO
        while(miResultset.next()) {
            
            // Variables temporales para almacenar las consultas
            String c_art=miResultset.getString("CÓDIGOARTÍCULO");
            String seccion=miResultset.getString("SECCIÓN");
            String n_art=miResultset.getString("NOMBREARTÍCULO");
            String importado=miResultset.getString("IMPORTADO");
            String p_orig=miResultset.getString("PAÍSDEORIGEN");
            double precio=miResultset.getDouble("PRECIO");
            Date fecha=miResultset.getDate("FECHA");
            
            // Objeto temporal de tipo Productos con el primer constructos
            Productos temProd=new Productos(c_art, seccion, n_art, importado, p_orig, precio, fecha);
            
            // Añadimos a la lista
            misProductos.add(temProd);
        }
        
        return misProductos;    
    }
}
```

2 - Codigo del Controlador

```
    package webProductos;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControladorProductos
 */
@WebServlet("/ControladorProductos")
public class ControladorProductos extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // 1 Creamos objeto de tipo ModeloProductos
    private ModeloProductos modeloProductos;
    
    // 2 DEFINIR EL DATASOURCE PARA CREAR LA DIRECTIVA RESOURCE
    // ENTRE PARÉNTESIS PONEMOS EL NOMBRE QUE LE PUSIMOS AL POOL DE CONEXIONES EN EL CONTEXT.XML
    @Resource(name="jdbc/productos")
    
    // 3 CREAR VARIABLE DE TIPO DATASOURCE PARA ALMACENAR EL POOL DE CONEXIONES (LA USAREMOS EN EL TRY)
    private DataSource miPool;
    
    
    // 4 CREAMOS EL METODO INIT DESDE EL QUE ARRANCA LA APLICACION
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        
        try {
        // 5 CONECTAMOS CON EL MODELO QUE RECIBIRA EL POOL
        modeloProductos=new ModeloProductos(miPool);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
    
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        // 7 OBTENER LISTA DE PRODUCTOS DESDE EL MODELO
        
        List<Productos> misProductos;
        
        try {
            misProductos=modeloProductos.getProductos();        
                
        // 8 AGREGAR LA LISTA DE PRODUCTOS AL REQUEST
        
        request.setAttribute("LISTAPRODUCTOS", misProductos);
        
        
        // 9 ENVIAR REQUEST A LA JSP
        
        RequestDispatcher miDispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/ListaProductos.jsp");
        
        miDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
    }

}
```

3 - Codigo del JSP

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    
    <%-- Importamos los paquetes que necesitaremos --%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*, webProductos.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<%

    
    List<Productos> losProductos=(List<Productos>) request.getAttribute("LISTAPRODUCTOS");
%>
     
<body>

    <%= losProductos %>

</body>
</html>
```

4 - Codigo de la clase Productos

```
    package webProductos;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Productos {
    
    // Variables para almacenar la información de cada campo de la BBDD
    
    private String cArt, seccion, nArt, importado, pOrig;
    private double precio;
    private Date fecha;
    
    // Constructor 1
    public Productos(String cArt, String seccion, String nArt, String importado, String pOrig, double precio, Date fecha) {
        super();
        this.cArt = cArt;
        this.seccion = seccion;
        this.nArt = nArt;
        this.importado = importado;
        this.pOrig = pOrig;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    // Constructor 2 (sin el códgio del artículo "cArt")
    public Productos(String seccion, String nArt, String importado, String pOrig, double precio, Date fecha) {
        super();
        this.seccion = seccion;
        this.nArt = nArt;
        this.importado = importado;
        this.pOrig = pOrig;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    
    // Metodo toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Productos [cArt=" + cArt + ", seccion=" + seccion + ", nArt=" + nArt + ", importado=" + importado
                + ", pOrig=" + pOrig + ", precio=" + precio + ", fecha=" + fecha + "]";
    }

    
    // GETTERS & SETTERS
    public String getcArt() {
        return cArt;
    }

    public void setcArt(String cArt) {
        this.cArt = cArt;
    }

    public String getSeccion() {
        return seccion;
    }

    public void setSeccion(String seccion) {
        this.seccion = seccion;
    }

    public String getnArt() {
        return nArt;
    }

    public void setnArt(String nArt) {
        this.nArt = nArt;
    }

    public String getImportado() {
        return importado;
    }

    public void setImportado(String importado) {
        this.importado = importado;
    }

    public String getpOrig() {
        return pOrig;
    }

    public void setpOrig(String pOrig) {
        this.pOrig = pOrig;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado si el log del servidor te muestra más información de porqué no se pudo instanciar el servlet? Que así a primera vista apostaría a que no encuentra el pool jdbc, pero tendrías que comprobarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios días mirando qué podía estar ocurriendo, resulta que era por los import del DataSource, en vez de "import javax.activation.DataSource;" tiene que ser "import javax.**sql**.DataSource;"... Una vez solucioné ese problema, se presentaron varios problemas más, que al final también pude solucionar, en este caso fueron problemas a la hora de consultar la BBDD, pues si bien el pool conecta sin problemas, daba conflicto 2 campos concretamente: el de fecha y el de precio, el 1º por el tipo de datos (lo tenia como un varchar en vez de date) y el segundo similar (varchar en vez de double).

Dejo mi experiencia por si a alguien le puede ayudar y sobre todo ahorrar los 3 o 4 días que me ha llevado a mí solucionarlo todo :)

Un saludo.